# Group images in nanogallery2 lightbox

Tags: lightbox, colorbox

I plan to make a website, where one picture is shown at the beginning. After that comes text and after the text the nanogallery2 is following.

What I want to do: I want to group the images together, so that when the user opens the first image on the page that also this first image will open into the nanogallery's lightbox as first element - so that user is able to go further on through the gallery from the first image on the site.

How can I do that?

Other question: When that will not be possible - how to use a different lightbox and then to group the pictures in another way together?

Thank you!

Danny

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: What I tried is the other way, to use the colorbox as other lightbox ... and  I changed the nGY2GThumbnailCustomLayer-div within the JS directly and put in there a <a href="..." rel="group1">... because if want to group the items. But this does not work.

Comment: Maybe try alternatives, for example, fancybox3 -  https://codepen.io/fancyapps/full/VGoRqO

Comment: Yes I already thought about that. But the "trigger-element" of the colorbox is shown in the html now...  as I said rel="group1" - but the colorbox does not trigger on it, because I think nanogallery2 makes some interferences. :-)
So I do not know if it not will be the same with fancybox3.

And I really like the lightbox of nanogallery2 - and really want to use that if possible.